# 'where' is not valid at this porsition

Tags: mysql

'where' is not valid at this position
please help
i'not good at english...
please find wrong points..

```
    enter code here
select @row_num := @row_num+1  AS RowNumber, a.rawid ,a.codename, 
ifnull(group_concat(a.dcname ) ,'-')  AS dcnames ,
    ifnull(group_concat(a.dcrawid) ,'-')  as dcrawids , b.cnt
from (
    SELECT id.codename ,d.dcname,d.rawid as dcrawid , id.rawid,
        @row_number:=CASE
            WHEN @customer_no = id.rawid 
              THEN 
                  @row_number + 1
              ELSE 
                   1
            END AS num,
        @customer_no:=id.rawid CustomerNumber
    FROM 
    (SELECT @customer_no:=0,@row_number:=0) as t,
    infocd id
    left JOIN infocddetail il ON id.RAWID = il.infocdrawid
    left JOIN dc d on d.rawid = il.dcrawid
)a 
left join (
    select id.rawid , count(f.rawid) cnt from infocd id
    left join form f on f.infocdrawid = id.rawid
    group by id.rawid
) b on b.rawid = a.rawid
group by a.codename ,a.rawid
where a.codename like '%2%';
```

'where' is not valid at this position
please help
i'not good at english...
please find wrong points..

Comment: Move your `WHERE` clause above your `GROUP BY` and you should be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to swap `where` and `group by` lines like below

```sql
where a.codename like '%2%'
group by a.codename ,a.rawid
;
```